# How to query X11 display resolution?

Tags: linux, x11

It seems like an simple problem, but I can't find the answer: How do you query (via X11) what monitors exist and their resolutions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out [display macros](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/display-macros.html) and [screen macros](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/screen-information.html) from the [Xlib manual](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/).

Specifically:

- From the [first link](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/display-macros.html): `ScreenCount()`, `ScreenOfDisplay()`
- From the [second link](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/screen-information.html): `WidthOfScreen()`, `HeightOfScreen()`

Answer (score 13):

This might be helpfull for cli and scripting

```
xwininfo -root
```

But xRandR might be more accurate, especially, when there is multiple monitor environment:

```
xrandr
```

Comment: It seem `xrandr` compared to `xwininfo -root` doesn't tell you about the monitor that is currently active though. However it's telling you about the monitor by proxy of the active root window.

Comment: `xprop -root` is also an alternative to `xwininfo`, but every `-root` option requires a root window. During `.xinitrc` you can not rely on the existence of the root window.

Answer (score 5):

If Xinerama is in use, try [`XineramaQueryScreens`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xineramaqueryscreens).  Otherwise, you may be able to assume a single screen and use `(X)WidthOfScreen`/`(X)HeightOfScreen.`

(Also see the other answer. It's remotely possible someone is using the old X screen model where your screens are `:x.0`, `:x.1`, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

For modern X servers, there's also the XRandR extension, which provides the most up-to-date model of multi screen layout information, including overlapping screens and dynamic screen changes.

Documentation of it is available in the [XRandR 1.3.1 Protocol spec](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/randrproto/randrproto.txt) and the [libXrandr man page](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/Xrandr.3.html).

Answer (score 4):

The library X11 working only with unix-like OS, so it is a not cross-platform solution.

**A full code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int
main(const int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    Display *display;
    Screen *screen;

    // open a display
    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    // return the number of available screens
    int count_screens = ScreenCount(display);

    printf("Total count screens: %d\n", count_screens);


    for (int i = 0; i < count_screens; ++i) {
        screen = ScreenOfDisplay(display, i);
        printf("\tScreen %d: %dX%d\n", i + 1, screen->width, screen->height);
    }

    // close the display
    XCloseDisplay(display);

   return 0;
}
```

**A compilation**

```
gcc -o setup setup.c -std=c11 `pkg-config --cflags --libs x11`
```

**A result** (actual for my computer)

```
Total count screens: 1
    Screen 1: 1366X768
```

**Based on:**

1. https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/opening.html
2. https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/display-macros.html
3. https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/screen-information.html
4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1829747/6003870

Comment: Thank you for providing the code. Do you know the answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987932/is-a-monitor-in-gtk3-the-same-as-a-screen-in-x11. I am asking if the screens you are finding in this code is the same as what Gtk3 3.22 calls monitors.

Comment: Any opinion/experience on Cygwin/Xming/etc.? X11 might not be portable, but if it's ported/adapted, it's as good as portable, no? Not my area of expertise - I'm used to using libraries like SDL2 that sweep this stuff under the rug.

Comment: This doesn't work with multiple monitors, at least on my Ubuntu setup. The question used the word "monitors", with an "s". The results this code gives me:
```Total count screens: 1
 Screen 1: 3520X1200
```
I'm using two "Join Displays", as denoted by the Display GUI settings. The first is 1920x1200. The second is a smaller, laptop display. The code results give you the total area covered by the two displays side-by-side. I want to programmatically determine the resolution of the primary display.

Answer (score 3):

## Clean `xrandr` output for imagemagick use

```
$ xrandr |grep \* |awk '{print $1}'
```

Results here in:

```
1920x1080
```

Comment: It is not related with the X11?

Answer (score 3):

**Python**

```
import os
from Xlib import X, display
d = display.Display()
s = d.screen().root
output = os.popen("xrandr --listmonitors | grep '*' | awk {'print $4'}").read().splitlines()
num_sc = s.xinerama_get_screen_count().screen_count
width = s.get_geometry().width
height = s.get_geometry().height
print("Total count screens: %s" % num_sc)
for i in range(num_sc):
    print("\tScreen %s(%s): %sX%s" % (i, output[i], width, height))
```

**Bash**

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
$ xrandr
$ xrandr | grep '*' | awk {'print $1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The program [xdpyinfo](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xdpyinfo) tells you almost everything about your X11 server.

```
$ xdpyinfo | sed -n '/^screen #0/{n;p}'
  dimensions:    3840x2160 pixels (696x391 millimeters)
```

For `ffmpeg`:

```
$ xdpyinfo | sed -n '/^screen #0/{n;s/^[ a-z:]*//;s/ .*//p}'
3840x2160
```