# How to get the screen & height width using c?

Tags: c, linux

Just learned that there is no pre-defined graphics library for C. I want to get the resolution of the current monitor screen.

Comment: Then you need to look up how it's done on your platform/OS

Comment: For Linux, see for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829706/how-to-query-x11-display-resolution.

Comment: You can use a cross-platform library for this, e.g. [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org) or [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org).

Comment: Are you looking for the size of the whole display or the current terminal? On a system with two monitors, which monitor are you looking for? Are you looking for the size in pixels or characters or something else?

Comment: Then you'll have to pick a graphics library (such as OpenGL or a native API) and use whatever methods it provides to query screen dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is simply not possible to answer as a "pure C" question; there is no "screen" in C, i.e. the language and its standard library never assumes that there is any kind of screen-like output device available.

You need to settle for a suitable library for a portable solution, or figure out how to talk directly to your target environment.